# Connecting two Cisco Routers on the same subnet via ethernet

Tags: cisco, routing

We have two routers.  One is a Cisco UC540, the other is a Cisco 891F.  The UC540 manages our VOIP but has been reaching maximum CPU usage.  We are trying to separate our data and our voice networks to mitigate the problem.

I have two servers on the Cisco 891F that have static ip addresses that I would like the computers on the UC540 to be able to connect to.

The Cisco 891F (which has the two servers) has an IP of 192.168.10.4 and the UC540 (which has our client computers) of 192.168.10.1.  Both are on the subnet 255.255.255.0.

I have a crossover cable if I need to use it.  However, how would I configure the two routers so the two servers with static ip addresses on the Cisco 891F (192.168.10.11 and 192.168.10.12)  can be reached from the computers on the UC540?

Comment: That's a total mess. Draw a picture might help us understand exactly what's going on. If you're using 192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0 everywhere then you should be able to just connect everything with a switch, no routing required.

Answer (score 0):

This is what routers do, they route between networks. If you want to connect the routers on ports dedicated to the router-to-router connection, that is easy, albeit you would need some way for each router to know which routes are on the other router. If the two routers connect through the LAN, you can also do this in several ways, but, again, each router should know which routes the other knows about.

You can statically defines the routes of the other router, but this doesn't scale, and any changes on one router would need to be reflected in the routes of the other router. This is the problem routing protocols were designed to solve. Routing protocols can dynamically reflect route change since each router will send any changes to the other router. With a small, two-router network, RIP works well enough. OSPF is faster to reflect routing changes. How you want to design this is completely up to you.